# Can velocity be positive and negative at the same time?

Tags: kinematics, vectors, coordinate-systems, velocity

[image: displacement along x and y axis]
If the displacement is (21m) along x and y axis and the car takes 3 seconds to travel the distance, will the displacement and velocity be positive and negative at the same time since its moving along (-x) and (+y) axis?

Edit: if an object is moving to the left you say it has a negative velocity like (- 3m/s) and if it moves straight toward (+y) axis it will have positive velocity like(+3m/s),what happens if the object is moving a portion to the left and a portion straight(toward +y axis) ?

Comment: Can you have a number that is both positive and negative?

Comment: Nope, however if   an object is moving to the left  you say it has a negative velocity like (- 3m/s) and if it moves straight toward (+y) axis it will have positive velocity like(+3m/s),what happens if the object is moving a portion to the left and a portion straight(toward +y axis) ?

Comment: Then you talk about velocity as a vector, which does not have a sign. Only it's components have signs.

Comment: Sorry i have a misconception, doesn't velocity have sign just like acceleration? For example if velocity has a (+) sign and acceleration opposes it then acceleration will have a (-) sign?

Comment: Neither velocity nor acceleration has a sign. They have a *magnitude* and a *direction*, and they have signed *components*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, signs only belong to **scalar** values. A vector like 
$$\vec a=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$$

has no sign in itself, only its coordinate values do. **If you do see** a sign on the vector, such as

$$-\vec a=\begin{pmatrix}1\\-2\end{pmatrix}$$

then that corresponds roughly to "taking the sign out of the bracket", similar to what you would do in basic algebra:

$$(b-c)=-(-b+c)$$

A negative sign on a vector can thus be understood both as the vector being flipped around, but also simply as both of its coordinate values having a negative sign (meaning, that they are "flipped over" and are now opposite along their axes).

And you would usually not say *a negative vector* but rather *the negative of a vector*, to emphasise that a negative vector doesn't really make sense whereas the negative of a vector just is a vector with an added negative sign.

**In conclusion**: A vector containing coordinates with mixed signs, $\begin{pmatrix}-1\\2\end{pmatrix}$, does not mean that the vector is neither negative nor positive. But you might call the vector as a whole *positive* if you want, because there is no negative sign in front of it.

Comment: @Zheer Yes. If you do put a sign on the vector, then it must be understood slightly differently as I explained. It is not wrong to put a sign on a vector, we just cannot think of it in the same way as we think about signs on scalar-values. A vector sign must be invented to this slightly different meaning that I've described.

Comment: thank you, so in this case the car is moving 21m in positive direction and - 21m in negative x direction?

Comment: @Zheer Yes, precisely. These two motions happen simultaneously. We collect them in brackets and call it a vector and name it *velocity*, but they are still two separate motions happening simultaneously, each with their own sign.

Comment: Thank you,i got a misconception, according to psychoras theorem, shouldn't the distance of x and y axis travelled be different?like 2^2+4^2=c^2?

Comment: @Zheer You are welcome. The distances traveled in either direction *are* different. You can calculate how far you move along the y-axis in, say, 10 seconds completely separated from whether or not there simultaneously also is a speed in the x-direction.

Comment: so the displacement for both negative x axis and positive y axis is the same however their distances is different, am i right?

Comment: @Zheer I'm not sure I understand. Distance and displacement are sort of the same thing, you just name it differently in different contexts. It is just "how far" there is to som position. If you have an object moving $-1 \,\mathrm{m/s}$ along the x-axis and $2 \,\mathrm{m/s}$ along the y-axis, then after 2 seconds, the object is now 2 metres to the left and 4 metres up. Had the object been moving with $-1 \,\mathrm{m/s}$ along the x-axis but **zero** speed along the y-axis, then it would *still* be 2 metres to the left after 2 seconds (and zero metres up).

Comment: Well explained, but I'm not sure about the last point of calling (-1 2) a "positive vector" simply because it has no negative sign in front of it. By that logic, -(1 -2) is a negative vector, despite being *the exact same vector*. A property of a vector shouldn't depend on how you choose to notate it. I'd say a vector is positive/negative if and only if all of its components are positive/negative. (-1 2) has both positive an negative components, so it's neither a positive vector nor a negative vector.

Comment: @NuclearWang You do have a point. -(1 -2) *is* a negative vector, though, or we could say: the negative of a vector. Namely the negative of the vector (1 -2). But its a bit ambiguous and the meaning not always clear, and I hope that is made clear from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

When we describe motion in one dimension we associate a sign with velocity, but in 2D, the perpendicular directions are independent of each other, so we need 2 numbers (corresponding with x and y direction). Here, with assumed x and y axes, you'll say velocity is positive in y direction and negative in x direction. It's like moving left *and forward* at the same time ( left-right doesn't depend on forward-backward).

Comment: Sorry i have a misconception, Well in this case the displacement is 21m along y and negative x axis, you can't say its +21 and - 21 at the same time, right?

Comment: So you mean it is - 21m in negative x direction and +21m in y direction?

Comment: @Zheer -21m in x direction or 21m in negative x direction

Answer (score 1):

When you draw the $x$ and $y$ axes you are really defining two directions and hence two unit vectors $\hat x$ and $\hat y$.

A vector $\vec a$ of **magnitude** $3$ pointing in the $y$ direction you would write as $\vec a=3\,\hat y$.
The magnitude is always a positive quantity.

Now what about a vector $\vec b$ of magnitude $4$ pointing in the  $(-x)$ direction which is in the opposite direction to that of the unit vector in $x$ direction, $\hat x$?

You could define a new unit vector pointing in the $(-x)$ direction, $\hat{x’}$ and so $\vec b = 4\,\hat{x’}$.

To simplify matters the idea of a **component** of a vector in a particular direction has been introduced and a component can be either positive or negative.

We can write  $\hat{x’}$ as $-1\, \hat x$ where $-1$ is the component of the vector  $\hat{x’}$ in the  $\hat{x}$ direction.

This means that $\vec b$ can be written as $-4 \,\hat x$ with component $-4$ in the  $\hat{x}$ direction.

So the vector $\vec b$ has a magnitude of $4$ and points in a direction opposite to that of unit vector $\hat x$.